# Get minimum value among the columns and apply function on the result dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a data frame `df_temp`:

```
index       timestamp             Output_Energy         Elevation       one     two  three
900 2016-06-20 15:00:00+05:30   48.49896354907767   54.46957706140074   25.0    30.0  40.0
901 2016-06-20 15:01:00+05:30   48.3233075379559    54.2501389347442    0.0     0.0    0.0
902 2016-06-20 15:02:00+05:30   48.146607818280856  54.03070866058405   0.0     0.0    0.0
903 2016-06-20 15:03:00+05:30   47.96891621606703   53.811287065389024  0.0     0.0    0.0
904 2016-06-20 15:04:00+05:30   47.79023387111256   53.59187496519667   0.0     0.0    0.0
905 2016-06-20 15:05:00+05:30   47.61054187943819   53.37247316433761   0.0     0.0    0.0
906 2016-06-20 15:06:00+05:30   47.42985481089121   53.153082456254396  0.0     0.0    0.0
907 2016-06-20 15:07:00+05:30   47.248157187430365  52.93370362427002   0.0     0.0    0.0
.
.
```

Firstly, I want to get the `min` value among the columns `one`, `two`, `three`. To do this I am using simple `if-else` conditions like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(df_temp)-1):
  if (df_temp.one[i]<df_temp.two[i] and df_temp.one[i]<df_temp.three[i]):
    do something
  elif (df_temp.two[i]<df_temp.one[i] and df_temp.two[i]<df_temp.three[i]):
    do something
  elif (df_temp.three[i]<df_temp.one[i] and df_temp.three[i]<df_temp.two[i]):
    do something
```

I would like to know a better way to do it as I want to make the code flexible for any number of columns.

Secondly, based on the result (i.e., column `one` has min value) I get, I want to perform an operation and another operation on the left-out columns (i.e., `two` and `three`) using following pre-defined function:

```
def charge_1(i):
  bat_state1=Battery1.charge(df_temp.timestamp[i],df_temp)
  bat_state2=Battery2.discharge(df_temp.timestamp[i])
  bat_state3=Battery3.discharge(df_temp.timestamp[i])
  df_temp.at[i+1,'one']=bat_state1
  df_temp.at[i+1,'two']=bat_state2
  df_temp.at[i+1,'three']=bat_state3
  return bat_state1, bat_state2, bat_state3
```

NOTE: This function is calling class methods `charge` and `discharge`.

Therefore, I would like to have suggestions on how I can make this function dynamic which perform operation based on result from previous task of finding `min` value.
For instance, if column `two` has `min` value `charge` method is called on `Battery2` and `discharge` on others.

*Open for clarifications, if needed*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minimum value in each column you have to apply `df.min()`, but you want to know which column has the minimum value. First we find the global minima and then compare that value to the minimum in each column:

```
>> target_columns = ["one", "two", "three"]
>> global_minima = df[target_columns].min().min()
>> column_has_global_minima = (df[target_columns].min() == global_minima)
>> column_has_global_minima
one     True
two     False
three   False
dtype: bool
>> minimum_columns = column_has_global_minima[column_has_global_minima].index.values
>> minimum_columns
['one']
```

For the second part of your question, I would suggest using the output of `column_has_global_minima`, a `pandas.Series` with boolean values indicating if the column minima matches the global minima (please consider what happens if two or more columns are tied in said value).

Assuming that you want to prepare your function to match any number of columns, you'll need to contain those `Battery{i}` objects in a sequence, maybe a `list`. In my answer, I assume that those objects are stores in the list `batteries`, and that the order of that list is the same as in `target_columns` (there's a correspondence between both). Also, I store the `bat_state` values in an output list (`bat_states`) and return that list (although maybe you want to unpack the list and return everything as a tuple: `return *bat_states`):

```
def charge_1(i):
    bat_states = list()
    for j, (column_name, column_contains_min) in enumerate(column_has_global_minima.items()):
        if column_contains_min:
            bat_state = batteries[j].charge(df_temp.timestamp[i], df_temp)
        else:
            bat_state = batteries[j].discharge(df_temp.timestamp[i])
        df_temp.at[i+1, column_name] = bat_state
        bat_states.append(bat_state)
    return *bat_states
```

Comment: when I executed the first part of the answer somehow I am getting ```True``` for all the three columns as output. Any guesses where I can be wrong?? Secondly, I would like to ask if it is possible to update the ```bat_state``` in respective columns of the data frame in the end?

Comment: Did you check column_has_global_minima? Is it possible that all the values in the group are the same?

Comment: About your second question, this line is supposed to do that: df_temp.at[i+1, column_name] = bat_state. Is not working for you?

Comment: Oh yeah I got the solution. It was checking at index 0 where all columns have zero value. But the part of df i added in the question has already values at first index. That's why i got all Trues. Also, that updating works :)

Comment: I have another question: is it possible to apply the charge function on the min with conditions? For instance, I want to call the function on column with min value till that value reaches 50 and then switch to next column with min value and apply the same condition and so on.

Comment: I think you can. I guess that you only need to change the for loop to a list of the columns names sorted by their minimum value (if I understand correctly). Is that what you need?